# How to create a stereo sound with independent channels in Adobe Audition?

Tags: audition

I'm trying to create a stereo sound with two independent channels. I mean, only the left channel is played via the left speaker, and only the right channel via the right speaker.

First I tried creating two mono sounds, and then inserting each one to a separate L/R channel. But the playback doesn't seem what I want! When I disconnect the left speaker, the right speaker has both the left and right sounds playing.

What should I do!? Am I missing some basics!? Any suggestions !?

Answer (score 2):

Crerate two mono tracks.  Put one of your mono sounds on one of them, the other or the other.  Pan one track hard L, the other hard R.

Comment: This is exactly what I do @laurence-payne . Maybe you can test it yourself and see if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same sound on both channels? or are they different sounds/instruments?

If they are the same sound and you want to make the sound wide, you need to add a bit of playback delay to one of them, I mean, moving a bit one of the tracks to the left or the right so they don't play exactly at the same time.

If they are different sounds, just panning one to the left and the other one to the right should be the only thing to do.

Comment: I use different sounds. I do what you say, but I don't know why I hear both sounds in the left speaker (after disconnecting the right speaker).

Comment: what if you use headphones? do you hear each sound panned correctly or u hear both in the center?

Comment: the same occurs with headphone.